# Clickable parent and child

Tags: android

This is my xml :

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/lnrFinish"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_green"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtInto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="End"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want if user click on `lnrFinish` print `a` and if click on `txtInto` print `b` and `a`

But my code not work after click on `txtInto` and only print `b`

I want print `a` anytime if even click on childs

Comment: `android:duplicateParentState="true"` add this line in TextView

Comment: Can we see the click listeners?